# Python read Android file Permission Denied [error 13] '/storage/emulated/0" [kivy/buildozer]

Tags: python, android, kivy, file-permissions, buildozer

I'm trying to upload a file to the sandboxed directory of the app so I can read it and manipulate it and give it back to the user
and I can neither read from it at the external_storage or copy it to the sandboxed directory... all the solutions I tried are saying access denied.

Now I need either to read from it and write another one at the sandboxed directory where I can manipulate files or directly upload it or copy it over there.

```
def slctfl(self, selection):
    if check_permission(Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== False:
        request_permission(Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    if check_permission(Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== False:
        request_permission(Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
    # I Logger Here <--> the check_permission (Read/write)  Both are True Which Means I have permissions
    if check_permission(Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==True: # How On Earth ?
        afileinext=open(selection[0],'r') # The Line That Is Causing This Big Error :'(
        for e in afileinext:
            with open(main_directory+'/Assets/Avito/error_log.txt', 'a') as file:file.write(e+'\n')
```

SelectFile is Called With filechooser of plyer which returns the path to the file(I wish if plyer could actually read the file)

```
filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.SelectFile)
```

Buildozer.spec

```
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,pyjnius,sqlite3,plyer
android.permissions = CALL_PHONE,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

I Tried Do it it with pyjnius and it says the same access denied error in the java way...
Tried to copy it with shutils to the sandboxed directory... same error.
I tried to do it with intents .. kind of the same error but this time saying the Intent exposed beyond the app.
I tried the verbose solutions of gpt almost got me to burn out...
gpt officially said it cannot solve this puzzling problem since the permissions are granted and she tried various solutions with me
Is There An Explicit documentation that says I cannot use commands that require permissions except from intents and activities?

The problem is simple I want to upload the file to the sandboxed directory... editing it at the external storage would be a bonus because I'll need later to handle the file back to the user
I expected this to be as easy as uploading a file on a webpage ....
please help me out I wasted too much time on this problem and I don't want to try another framework or other programming language because the ui of the app is already built with kivy.
billions of 'why?' are popping in my mind... why would it says access denied inside an 'if' that makes sure the access is NOT DENIED.

Thank You So Much!
Happy Coding! And Happy Debugging!

Comment: Consider editing your question to make it more readable.